# вставка html-тега в body на javaScript

Tags: javascript

Следующая задача на JavaScript:

нужно в body обернуть весь контент в div таким образом:

было: 
`<body> something </body>` 
стало: 
`<body><div id="newdiv"> something </div></body>`

пробовал использовать `window.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div id="translatebody">')`, но новый div вставляется не так как мне нужно:
`<body><div id="newdiv"></div> something </body>`

Comment: Вам нужно не "вставить div", а "обернуть контент в div".

Comment: да, все верно, я поправил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="newdiv">' + document.body.innerHTML + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Если используете jquery то можно сделать так:

```
$("body").wrapInner("<div id="newdiv"></div>");
```